# Downloading and installing ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, download

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 version, and I want to download ArcGIS Server with sutable version to my desktop.

From where can I download it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ESRI support should help you with this.

Comment: Spacedman is correct. The answer is you log in to your ESRI support site and go to the downloads section.

Comment: It's not actually Support but Customer Service that should be contacted.  10.1 is in Extended support status; I doubt you can get a new license of 10.1 Server (and there have been many fixes in the releases of 10.2, 10.2.1, 10.2.2, 10.3, 10.3.1, 10.4, and 10.4.1 since)

Answer (score 4):

Esri software downloads start in [MyEsri](https://my.esri.com/).

If you cannot access this, you're not the authorized person at your organization. You'll need to either work with Esri Customer Service to get added to your org as a qualified person, or you'll need to search out your qualified person at your org and have them make the download on your behalf.

Quote from MyEsri : How do I download Esri software?

> Esri software is available to download on My Esri through the My
>   Organizations tab, then click the Downloads sub tab. Here is a direct
>   link.
>
> ISO file downloads and requests to have physical media shipped are
>   located under the Backup Media navigation menu which appears when
>   Downloads is selected.
>
> The download page is available for those who have the Download
>   software permissions. If you do not have that permission, you can
>   request permissions.
>
> The downloads listed are those your organization is entitled to. If
>   you feel this list is incorrect, please contact Esri Customer Service
>   or call 1-888-377-4575. If you are located outside of the United
>   States, please contact your distributor.